# Saving to child table with springboot+jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have trouble in saving... fetch from child table is working
Here is my **parent table pojo**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Dei_Resources")
public class DeiResources {

    private int id;
    private String employeeId;
    private Set<DeiResourceType> deiResourceType;
    //other setters getters not included
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "deiResource", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<DeiResourceType> getDeiResourceType() {
        return deiResourceType;
    }
```

**Child Table pojo**

```
@Entity
public class DeiResourceType implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private int resourceId;
    private String typeValue;
    @JsonBackReference
    private DeiResources deiResource;

    //other setters getters not included
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resourceId", referencedColumnName="id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public DeiResources getDeiResource() {
        return deiResource;
    }
```

I have DeiResourcesRepository in place, in my service Im trying this

```
DeiResources dei = new DeiResources();
DeiResourceType deii =  new DeiResourceType();
Set<DeiResourceType> deiResourceType = new HashSet<DeiResourceType>();
deii.setTypeValue("Driver");
deiResourceType.add(deii);
dei.setEmployeeId("unique1");
dei.setDeiResourceType(deiResourceType);
deiResourcesRepository.save(dei);
```

Getting this error

> [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-02291:
>   integrity constraint (DEI_ADMIN.DEI_RESOURCE_TYPE_R01) violated -
>   parent key not found

In DeiResourceType table I have added foreign key constrain with Parent table ID. How can I get rid of this error, any suggestion/help ?

Comment: Is the type `Driver` already existing in the Database-Table `DeiResourceType`?

Comment: yes, but there is no unique key constraint for typeValue

Answer (score 0):

First, in SQL there is no Child/Parent pattern. Thats why the imagination of a structure like a real family is wrong. In this example a parent can not be a child, in the real world everyone who is parent is a child too!

We only have two Tables who have a 1-n relation respecting the *constraint* that every DeiResource must have a DeiResourceType! As long as this constraint keeps it integrity, there is no exception.

**This in mind** you call the constructor of two entitys **but** you save only one (you save the DeiResource without DeiResourceType). So you save a Resource without a type. But the constraint that every *DeiResource must have a DeiResourceType* is broken and the database has no integrity anymore and the Exception is thrown!

You have two options:

- You save the DeiResourceType first and then the DeiResource
- You load a existing DeiResourceType first, wire it to the DeiResource and save the DeiResource then.

I would prefer the second method to avoid duplicates in the Table "DeiResourceType".

(By the way, theese constraints can be deferrable, a old, forgotten and mighty magic)